# autocomplete suggest from multiple columns and prevent duplicate

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I want autocomplete value from two columns of MySql database table, One column have multiple similar values, In autocomplete window in case of similarity it should only display one of the similar values. And after select it should not be suggested in autocomplete window in next row.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="aTeam"  id="team_1" class="team"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  id="score_1" ></td>
</tr>
<button type="button" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('focus','.team',function(){
var type = $(this).data('type');
if(type ==='aTeam' )autoTypeNo= 0;
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'fetch.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.aTeam,
                        value: item.aTeam,
                        data : item
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {                         
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#team_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.aTeam);
        $('#score_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.score);
    }               
  });
});

//add row
   var i=$('table tr').length;
   $("#addRow").on('click',function(){
       html = '<tr>';
       html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="aTeam" id="team_'+i+'" class="team"></td>';
       html += '<td><input type="text" id="score_'+i+'"></td>';
       html += '</tr>';
       $('table').append(html);
       i++;
   });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");

    if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
       $type = $_POST['type'];
       $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
       $query = $db->prepare("SELECT aTeam, bTeam FROM teams where UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%' limit 10 ");
       $query->execute();
       $data= array();

   $i = 0;
       while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {

           $data[$i]['aTeam'] = $row['aTeam'];
           $data[$i]['bTeam'] = $row['bTeam'];
           $data[$i]['score'] = $row['score'];
   ++$i;
       }  
       echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share sample ouput of `echo json_encode($output);`? Add it to your question, or if it's too long, share it via Pastebin.com

Comment: @SallyCJ -  i have multiple names in this column that's why it shows multiple same names, And this is the output `[{aTeam: "john"}, {aTeam: "john"}]
0
:
{aTeam: "john"}
1
:
{aTeam: "john"}`

Comment: Please check my answer/code and let me know if it helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119410/remove-duplicate-results-in-autocomplete 100% functional ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (read the `// {comment here}` and just compare the code with yours to see what changed)

```
$(document).on('focus','.team',function(){
let type = $(this).data('type');

// `autoTypeNo` isn't used anywhere, so I commented out this.
//if(type ==='aTeam' )autoTypeNo= 0;

$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'fetch.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
               let selected = [],
                   uniques = [],
                   choices = [];

               $('tr .team[id^="team_"]').each(function(){
                 let value = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
                 if (value && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                   selected.push(value);
                 }
               });

               data.forEach(item => {
                 let value = item.aTeam.trim().toLowerCase(),
                     value2 = item.bTeam.trim().toLowerCase();

                 if (uniques.indexOf(value) < 0 && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                   choices.push({
                     label: item.aTeam,
                     value: item.aTeam,
                     data: item,
                     type: 'aTeam'
                   });
                   uniques.push(value);
                 }

                 if (uniques.indexOf(value2) < 0 && selected.indexOf(value2) < 0) {
                   choices.push({
                     label: item.bTeam,
                     value: item.bTeam,
                     data: item,
                     type: 'bTeam'
                   });
                   uniques.push(value2);
                 }
               });

               response(choices);
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // Strips the 'team_' part, leaving just the number.
        let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);

        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        $('#score_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.score);
        $(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type); // Change to the correct type?

        // Cancels default action, so that the above `jQuery.val()` call works.
        return false;
    }
  });
});

//add row
// 'i' is too generic, so I renamed it to 'row_num'.
   var row_num=$('table tr').length;
   $("#addRow").on('click',function(){
       // Increment before used.
       row_num++;

       let html = '<tr>';
       html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="aTeam" id="team_' + row_num + '" class="team"></td>';
       html += '<td><input type="text" id="score_' + row_num + '"></td>';
       html += '</tr>';
       $('table').append(html);

       // Optional, but I like to focus on the `input` in the row that was just added.
       $('#team_' + row_num).select();
   });
```

### UPDATE

I updated the JS code *(above)*.

And note that for the PHP part, I changed the `$query` from:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT aTeam, bTeam FROM teams where UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%' limit 10 ");
```

to:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT aTeam, bTeam, score FROM teams where ( aTeam LIKE '".$name."%' OR bTeam LIKE '".$name."%' ) limit 10 ");
```

because without the `OR bTeam LIKE '".$name."%'`, for example if you typed "d" and there were no `aTeam` starting with "d", then you know what would happen..

Comment: sorry! i made some changes to the question, your code makes autocomplete unique, which works. but its not preventing duplicate on next row. And i want to search aTeam and bTeam to be searched together in the same field, As i have asked in the question **I want autocomplete value from two columns of MySql database table** .  And after select i want score field of relevant teams also. THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER.

Comment: plz make some changes to the answer according to my new edit.

Comment: Ok, so the `input` box will show autocomplete *suggestions* from both the `aTeam` and `bTeam` columns in the MySQL table, right? Which means, if there was a row where `aTeam` is 'John' and `bTeam` is 'Johnny', both 'John' and 'Johnny' will appear in the *same* autocomplete suggestions menu?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. It worked well for me, but if it doesn't for you, let me know and I'll adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot its perfect now.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! But sorry, I forgot to add (back) the inline comments.. however, I'm pretty sure you could understand the changes I made, which *mainly in the `success` callback for the AJAX request*. :)

Comment: its ok ,its understandable.